# Can table be locked in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, locking

I'm developing an web app and must send valid error messages to clients if something go wrong, if table is locked I must send error about it, can be table locked in oracle databse? if it can't I just wont implement this functionality.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes table can be locked in orcale. if two process tries to write (update or insert) in table and then neither commit or close connection. It will be locked.

You can replicate it by editing or running update query it with tool with autocommit off and don't run commit or rollback, you will get locked,, while  you try to access same table from different tool or code.

If you have TOAD simply edit the row of table and don't save. Simultaneously try to update that table from you code.

However, you application has almost zero chance to lock the table, as you will be having some connection timeout after the your connection will be closed. But there is chance that someother process will lock the table.

Comment: This is wrong. Concurrent updates or inserts, will ***not*** lock the *table*, they will only the involved *rows*. Plus: the table will always be available for read access. There is a huge difference between a "table lock" and a "row lock"

Comment: OP is looking for anykind of lock. He will have to send error message to user in case of row lock also.